# Best way to create a dynamic template with dynamic data base

Tags: java, angularjs

I need to create a dynamic form from dynamic data base. 
I would like your opinion on which framework, approach or technique to use.

The idea is the user create a custom form and define somes rules.

Currently, I'm working with java + angular + sql server or mysql.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a dynamic language like JavaScript and a schema-less database like Mongo which makes it easier to deal with.

Javascript on the client(angularjs), on server with nodejs(express/restify) and the database with MongoDB(schema-less).

In fact I built a search solution with Elasticsearch instead of Mongo and everything else was the same.

Comment: Thanks @Chirdeep, I think that to save the structure of my form in a NonSQL is a good approach.

Comment: @JonasRodrigues not only NoSql you really want the server-side to be dynamic and not a statically typed language like Java/C# otherwise you will not benefit much from NoSQL. Although with this approach, you will have to trust your client application more as server will stick everything in the database that it receives as a valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks again @Chirdeep for your explanation.

Comment: @JonasRodrigues please mark this as an answer, so others could also benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good, please go ahead, In Joomla you can achive this by custom module easily, you can create custom component for adminside management functionality.

You must need to know about Module creation for your front side website but for admin side you can create component using http://www.component-creator.com. It is free for single table and using this you will easily get the concept how you have to manage data in your adminside.

Comment: Thanks @Info Truth. I'll take a look to component creator.